# How to get Airsim in Windows to send data to Px4 with Gazebo backend in WSL2?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin, px4

Not able to connect px4 to GazeboDrone, it shows
*"Waiting for connection - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"*

##### The objective is:

Using GazeboDrone and Airsm, I would like render the visualization of a drone using Airsim but the phyiscs engine from Gazebo, such that the sensor data is provided by Airsim.

Px4 is running in WSL2 in a docker container
Airsim (latest)/UE(4.27) are running in Windows 10
[settings.json](https://gist.github.com/schakour/23dde08b19843105115975cb625f72d0)

#### Details of what was to find the answers:

I cloned the Airsim repo and built it in WSL2 using GCC8 and G++8
I followed the steps in :  [GazeboDrone](https://microsoft.github.io/AirSim/gazebo_drone/)
I used the clang compiled environment provided in :  [Airsim build](https://github.com/microsoft/AirSim/releases)
As well as the instruction here:   [Integrate Airsim with Px4 in WSL2](https://microsoft.github.io/AirSim/px4_sitl_wsl2/)
Including the modification of the ./GazeboDrone's main.cpp  of:
`msr::airlib::MultirotorRpcLibClient client("my_ip_address");`

The part that I didn't find is the env var :  PX4_SIM_HOST_ADDR  in

> ROMFS/px4fmu_common/init.d-posix/rcS

and when I go into this file to add

```
# If PX4_SIM_HOST_ADDR environment variable is empty use localhost.
if [ -z "${PX4_SIM_HOST_ADDR}" ]; then
    echo "PX4 SIM HOST: localhost"
    simulator start -c $simulator_tcp_port
else
    echo "PX4 SIM HOST: $PX4_SIM_HOST_ADDR"
    simulator start -t $PX4_SIM_HOST_ADDR $simulator_tcp_port
fi
```

I don't find anywhere a call like this :   `simulator start`

Note that this is fork of PX4 that's been modified for R&D